# integral of an exponential function contains a summation

Tags: integration, summation, exponential-function

For the following, summation on the exponential function confuses me.

$\int_{0}^{t} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{\rho_k}  e^{ \Big(-\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{x}{\rho_k} \Big)}dx$

I took the integral. Can anybody tell me if it looks correct?

$\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{\rho_k} \Big[ \frac{1}{{ -\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{\rho_k}} } e^{ \Big(-\sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{x}{\rho_k} \Big)} \Big]_{0}^t$

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the summand is independent of $k$ so it's just $Kx/\rho$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist thank you. Actually $\rho$ is dependent of $k$. It should be like $\rho_{k}$.